# How to render two columns preserving all whitespace after the first column with awk or alternative?

Tags: shell, awk

my output comes in human-readable figures with one space followed by directory names:

I am currently using ...

```
awk '{ printf "%-20s %-40s\n", $1, $2 }'
```

**input**

```
1G foo
1.5M foo baz 
5K foo spaces in this directory
```

**output**

```
1G    foo
1.5M  foo 
5K    foo
```

**desired**

```
1G    foo
1.5M  foo baz 
5K    foo spaces in this directory
```

How to split into two columns with whitespace delimiter preserving all whitespace in the second column using awk or alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ awk '{ printf "%-20s ", $1; $1=""; print $0 }' input 
1G                    foo
1.5M                  foo baz
5K                    foo spaces in this directory
```

Resetting the leading columns to an empty string is the usual trick to print all the remaining fields/columns.